# C - insert lines from very big file into array

Tags: c, arrays, file, pointers, malloc

First of all, I'm quite new with C, and I know this is a very repeated question, however, I could not find anything that could help me with my problem.

Here is my code:
It takes a text file and stores each line in an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    char buffer[600];
    char *lines[10000];
    int i = 0;

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file))
    {

        lines[i] = malloc(sizeof(buffer));
        strcpy(lines[i], buffer);
        i++;
        free(lines[i]);
    }

    fclose(file);


    return 1;
}
```

This works fine for small text files.

However it doesn't with large ones (even setting buffer and lines with much bigger numbers). Actually, if I increment buffer[] and *lines[] like 1000000 bytes, it doesn't give anything (if I understood well, it gives undefined behaviour). And I need to get this work with a 100.000 lines file with variable length lines,

So, how could I declare a very large array so I can pass each line? Since, as I exposed, it doesn't work with a large file.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I would recommend you to use a linked list. You may not have a block with that much RAM for this array(maybe multiple blocks).

Comment: And you should test if `malloc` returns `NULL`

Comment: And in your example you allocate RAM and store the address of the allocated RAM in the lines array and free it afterwards(you didn't even use the allocated space)

Comment: You allocate memory for `lines[i]` and `strcpy` into that memory. Then you increment `i` and call `free(lines[i])`. As a result, you attempt to free an uninitialized pointer. Simply remove the `free(lines[i])` for now. It's good practice to free the memory when you're done with it, but it's not absolutely required. The OS will clean up the mess when the program exits.

Comment: First, you should specific your platform, which is very sense for C or Cpp. Second, if your program is running on VS,  allocating such a lager memory may be limited by compiler, which you can types the /z command line to VS to support lager memory allocation. Finally, your program allocates line but free it immediately, your compiler may never compile it because optimism.

Comment: First, you should specific your platform, which is very sense for C or Cpp. Second, if your program is running on VS,  allocating such a lager memory may be limited by compiler, which you can types the /z command line to VS to support lager memory allocation. Finally, your program allocates line but free it immediately, your compiler may never compile it because optimism.

Comment: Well, your question misses at least one information: *How* does it not work? Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Then read user3386109's comment and if it helps you ask her/him kindly to make this an answer and mark it.

Comment: Rather than allocate to the size of the buffer, allocate to the size used.  `lines[i] = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica could you explain a little more? How different is that from lines[i] = malloc(sizeof(buffer));?

Comment: `sizeof(buffer)` is always 600.  `strlen("Hello world\n") + 1` is 13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char *lines[10000];` is just an array of pointers to the lines, not the array (memory) that is going to store the actual lines.

`malloc` is allocating a chunk of memory for each line, you are suppose to call `free` only when you are done using this chunk.

If you remove the `free` your solution would work, but you need to remember to `free` at some other point.

Comment: That made the trick! The problem now is how to free each memory chunk. Would be a good implemention by calling a for loop i times calling free(lines[i]) each iteration? Because as I could see, I can't make free(lines).

Comment: @Santiago you are correct, you should iterate the lines array and free each entry that you have called malloc previously for. (Notice not to call free on indexes where you didn't)

Comment: This approach can still cause problems when you need to allocate high amount of memory, because as someone pointed out here, there may not even be that much contiguous memory available. Yes, `10000 * sizeof(char *)` which is 80k bytes on a 64 bit machine may work, but be careful with higher amounts.

Answer (score 1):

> And I need to get this work with a 100.000 lines file with variable length lines,
>
> So, how could I declare a very large array so I can pass each line?

This line

```
char *lines[10000];
```

gives you a variable with automatic storage duration - often called a local variable.

On most systems such a variable are located on a stack and most systems have a fixed limit for the size of the stack and thereby also a limit for the size of such a local variable.

So if you change the code to

```
char *lines[1000000];
```

to be able to handle larger files, it is likely that the variable use too much memory on the stack, i.e. you have a stack overflow.

A simple solution is to allocate the variable dynamically. Like:

```
char **lines = malloc(1000000 * sizeof *lines);
```

This will allocate 1000000 char-pointers and you can use `lines` as if it's an array - for instance like:

```
lines[i] = malloc(sizeof(buffer));
```

For something like this I'll also recommend that you take a look at `realloc` so that you can adjust the size of memory as needed.

Besides that your use of `free` seems strange and it's for sure wrong as you increment `i` between the `malloc` and the `free`.

Comment: So, you say that it would be best to directly allocate the variable dynamically and expand the chunk as I need? Also, why **? Sorry if it's a basic question, but I have just a couple of weeks of learning

Comment: @Santiago The `**` is because you need a "pointer to pointer to char" so that you can use it as an array of "pointers to char".

Comment: @Santiago yes, I would start by allocating e.g. 1000 char-pointers. If I later found out the file was larger, I would use `realloc` to increase the size of allocated memory. Anyway - start by fixing the case where you allocate "a big chunck". When that works move on to implement the `realloc` solution

Comment: You should also include a linked list solution here. Reallocating that much memory is for sure a problem.

Comment: @Victor notice that reallocation are only needed for the array of pointers (i.e. `lines`). The individual line do not need reallocation. So even with 1.000.000 lines, it's just a few MB which shouldn't be a problem. And reallocation shall not increment the size by 1 but with a larger value so that the number of reallocations will be small.

Comment: I've implemented your solution and it worked! Now I've got to figure out how to reallocate the memory according to the input file. I need to ask you just one more thing: how do I know the size I reserve for **lines?. I tried with a 147 lines file, and char **lines = malloc(1 * sizeof *lines);  for example just worked fine. I'm a bit confused as how this works.

Answer (score 1):

You can allocate any space just as big as you need. So you will get rid of the fixed and limited numbers.

I have "massaged" your example in this way. The only thing I didn't is a first round through the file to obtain the longest line. So I kept the fixed buffer length.

1. Allocate only as many pointer to the lines as you need. For this you define a pointer to pointers to `char`.
2. Allocate only as many characters for each line as you need. This is done most conveniently with the function `strdup()`. If your library doesn't have it (it is not standard) you can replace it with the right combination of `strlen()`, `malloc()`, and `strcpy()`. How to do this is left as an exercise for you. ;-)
3. Handle allocation errors, especially if you plan to read huge files.
4. Free the allocated memories blocks, the sequence for the lines is not important. But `lines` has to be kept until all `lines[*]` are freed.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    char buffer[600];
    char **lines = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file))
    {
        lines = realloc(lines, (i + 1) * sizeof (char*));
        if (lines == NULL)
        {
            // any error handling you like...
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        lines[i] = strdup(buffer);
        if (lines[i] == NULL)
        {
            // any error handling you like...
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        i++;
    }

    fclose(file);

    // work with the lines

    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
    {
        free(lines[j]);
    }
    free(lines);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Some notes:

- Because of the `realloc()` on each line the run time of you program will scale bad for files with a giant number of lines. To improve this you might like to use some better algorithm, for example by allocating in steps of growing numbers. But this is a completely different issue.
- You don't need to free allocated memory yourself at all if you need the memory until the end of the program. The C runtime will then free the memory automatically.

Comment: Using `realloc()` to increment the size by 1 tends to lead to quadratic behaviour as the memory is often copied from the smaller space to the larger space.  It is generally better to track two numbers — the number of pointers allocated and the number used.  When the number of pointers used would exceed the number allocated, double the number of pointers allocated (making sure 0 doesn't "double" to 0 — I often use 2N+2).  If you're worried about the space used, you can free the unwanted pointers when the loop ends with a shrinking `realloc()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's what I meant by "will scale bad" and considering the experience level of the OP I didn't want to go deeper.